# Manual eav join best way?

Tags: collection, eav, sql

If i have a product collection in a multi store environment and i wish to also retrieve a specific attributes value from another store with my collection result, how is the best way to do this?

For example, i have english, french and german store.

Each product has a custom attribute, called company_description.  I want to be able to be able to get the collection from one store but also retrieve the company_description as it is set in the other 2 store views also.

It needs a join but i dont how best to do the manual eav joining.

So -

```
// In english store context
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('company_description');
```

I then need to do something with a join so i can get all 3 descriptions as:

```
company_description
company_description_fr
company_description_de
```

Comment: No these are separate - im asking here how the join should be constructed manually for an eav type join i.e. join to get the attribute id, value id etc

Comment: I would think about having three attributes. Obviously the attribute is not store view specific. Help yourself, create two more attributes and you don't have any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::joinAttribute ($alias, $attribute, $bind, $filter, $joinType, $storeId)`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.html#joinAttribute) you can specify a store.  Once joined the attribute is in place and any future uses refer to that new table, useful if you want to filter it too.  `joinAttribute()` adds to select anyway so there is no need to use `addAttributeToSelect()` afterwards.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId(0)    // To ensure all other attributes are default
    ->addAttributeToSelect('company_description')

    // French store is 3
    ->joinAttribute('company_description_fr', 'catalog_product/company_description',
                    'entity_id', null, 'inner', 3)

    // German store is 2
    ->joinAttribute('company_description_de', 'catalog_product/company_description',
                    'entity_id', null, 'inner', 2);
```